How to generate an array of given size, with one field populated?
I would like to create a function that given a value of any type, a dimension of the one-dimensional array and the column to set, will return a one-dimensional array filled with null values except for one given value at a given position.
The code bellow is what I created tentatively to do it but it does not work:
create function arraycol(v anyelement,n int,i int)
  returns anyarray language plpgsql as $$ 
declare r anyarray; 
begin
    r=array_fill(null,array[n]);
    r[i]=v;
    return r;
end $$;

Is it possible to have the function return a polymorphic array type?
is it possible to create a variable of polymorphic element type?

The description is hard to follow. The "dimension of the unidimensional array" is that just its size? Could you give an example of use? arraycol(1, 5, 2) produces ARRAY[null, 1, null, null, null]?

So is this answered properly?

I think yes, to the best of the possibilities of plpgsql!

You were close.
r anyarray; isn't valid syntax to declare a variable of the polymorphic input type anyarray. To declare a variable of polymorphic input type use the %TYPE construct:
DECLARE
   array_element v%TYPE;

Unfortunately in this case, we only have a parameter of type anyelement to work with, which makes it tricky. See:

How do I get the type of an array's elements?

I use an OUT parameter or type anyarray instead, to simplify.
Also, you need to pass the actual element type to the function array_fill(). An un-typed null won't do. To skip variable declaration completely I produce the typed null value ad-hoc with NULLIF(v, v):
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arraycol (v anyelement, n int, i int, OUT r anyarray)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
BEGIN
   r := array_fill(NULLIF(v, v), ARRAY[n]);
   -- if i > n then this assignment auto-fills positions in between with null
   r[i] := v;
END
$func$;

Equivalent variant without array_fill(). In the assignments, an un-typed null works:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arraycol (v anyelement, n int, i int, OUT r anyarray)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
BEGIN
   r[1] := null;  -- assuming 1-based indexes!
   r[i] := v;     -- auto-fills positions in between with null
   IF n > i THEN
      r[n] := null;
   END IF;
END
$func$;

fiddle
Same call, same result. Example:
SELECT arraycol (1, 3, 2);




arraycol




{NULL,1,NULL}



Of course, I'd put in checks to enforce sane input. Like, enforce dimension input > 1.

This one had me stumped. Excellent explanation. Would it be correct to say %TYPE is similar to templates and generics in other languages?

@Schwern:  Would it be correct? Depends on the other language. %TYPE copies the data type of a template.

Postgres won't let you declare r anyarray; or declare r v%type[]. What it won't mind at all is if you already have it declared by that point:
create function arraycol(v anycompatiblenonarray,n int,i int, 
  r anyarray default array[null])--here, just don't tell anyone
  returns anycompatiblearray language plpgsql as $f$ 
begin
    r=array_fill(nullif(v,v),array[n]);
    r[i]=v;
    return r;
end $f$;

It's not strictly the same as returning via an OUT parameter - r's argmode is the default IN but effectively, it's achieving pretty much the same goal, pretty much the same way as that.
Demo at db<>fiddle:
select arraycol(1,3,2);
select arraycol('some_text',3,2);
select arraycol(true,3,2);
select arraycol('{"a":true}'::jsonb,3,2);
select arraycol(tstzrange('now','tomorrow','[]'),3,2);




arraycol




{NULL,1,NULL}






arraycol




{NULL,some_text,NULL}






arraycol




{NULL,t,NULL}






arraycol




{NULL,"{"a": true}",NULL}






arraycol




{NULL,"["2024-05-10 14:05:47.265587+01","2024-05-11 00:00:00+01"]",NULL}



One thing it won't do is give you arrays of arrays.
select arraycol(array[1,2,3],3,2);


ERROR:  function arraycol(integer[], integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 17: select arraycol(array[1,2,3],3,2);
                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.


Even if you swap out anycompatiblenonarray for a regular anycompatible

ERROR:  could not find array type for data type integer[]


Which might be for the better, because all this feels very wrong.

Here's how you can also do that in plain SQL:
create function arraycol_arr(
  v anycompatiblenonarray,n int,i int, 
  r anyarray default array[null])
  returns anycompatiblearray immutable strict parallel safe as $f$ 
select arr[:i-1]||array[v]||arr[i+1:]
from(select array_fill(nullif(v,v),array[n]) arr)_;
$f$ language sql;

create function arraycol_sql_gens_agg(
  v anycompatiblenonarray,n int,i int, 
  r anyarray default array[null])
  returns anycompatiblearray immutable strict parallel safe as $f$ 
select array_agg(case x when i then v end)
from(select generate_series(1,n)x)_;
$f$ language sql;

Which according to the tests at the end of the demo is a nice way to butcher your performance.
